# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method Double Round(Double, Int32, System.MidpointRounding) method

Tags: linq, double, rounding, linqer

I've tried the below LINQ Query in Linqer it is working fine but it is giving the below error while i tried with C#

```
from IHeal_Mnt_Tickets in iHealEntities.iHeal_Mnt_Tickets
    where
        Tickets.Active == 1 &&
        Tickets.MntID == 1 &&
        Tickets.InsertedOn >= fromdate && 
        Mnt_Tickets.InsertedOn <= todate &&
        (new string[] { "Resolved", "Assigned" }).Contains(Tickets.status)
        group Tickets by new {
            Tickets.Instance
        } into g
            select new {
              Instance = g.Key.Summus_Instance,
              Assigned = (Int64?)g.Count(p => p.iHealID != null),
              resolved = (System.Int64?)g.Sum(p => (p.status == "Resolved" ? 1 : 0)),
              domain = (System.Int64?)g.Sum(p => (p.status == "Assigned" ? 1 : 0)),
              iHeal_Closure = (Decimal?)Math.Round((Double)(Double)g.Sum(p => (p.iHeal_Cur_status == "Resolved" ? 1 : 0)) * 1.0 / (Double)g.Count(p => p.iHealID != null) * 100, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
            };
```

The error is

```
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Round(Double, Int32, System.MidpointRounding)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."
```

Comment: MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero is not supported in LINQ query

Answer (score 10):

Not everything that's supported in the BCL has a direct equivalent in SQL. Given that this is the final part of the query, the simplest approach would be to just write a query which fetched all the data you need *without* rounding etc, and then transform that data into your preferred format using a local query:

```
var dbQuery = from item in source
              where filter
              select projection;
// The AsEnumerable() part is key here
var localQuery = from item in dbQuery.AsEnumerable()
                 select complicatedTransformation;
```

Using `AsEnumerable()` effectively just changes the compile-time type... so that the `Select` call is `Enumerable.Select` using a delegate rather than `Queryable.Select` using an expression tree.

I would hope that you could make the final transformation *much* simpler than your current approach though - things like `(Double)(Double)` really aren't necessary... and any time you convert from `double` to `decimal` or vice versa, you should question whether that's necessary or desirable... it's generally better to stick to *either* binary floating point *or* decimal floating point, rather than mixing them.