# Math.Round in linq to entities vs linq to objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The behavior of the following are different and it's hard to manage, depending on if the query was executed or not:

```
using (var db = new DbContext()) 
{
    db.Entities.Select(x => Math.Round(0.5)).First(); // return 1
    db.Entities.ToList().Select(x => Math.Round(0.5)).First(); // returns 0
    db.Entities.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Math.Round(0.5)).First(); // returns 0
}
```

Of course my actual code perform an operation on `x`. this is for simplicity.

I know there is [Math.Round with MidpointRounding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Math_Round_System_Decimal_System_MidpointRounding_) but it's not supported by Linq to Entities:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Double Round(Double,
>   System.MidpointRounding)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

My question is, other than executing the query and rounding in memory, is there a way to have the same behavior in c# and Linq to Entities?

Is there a way to set the default behavior of Math.Round to always use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`?

Comment: Instead of `ToList` when you want your Linq code run in memory instead of translated to SQL you can use `AsEnumerable` to avoid the unneeded intermediate list.  This is also an issue when doing string comparisons as often DBs are setup to do those case insensitive and you cannot tell them otherwise.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to write `Math.Round(0.5)` without all the LINQ stuff?

Comment: @juharr Yeah of course, I just put ToList() for simplicy... updated the query to be more general. the point is not having to care about wether the query is executed or not. as for string comparision. Equals with StringComparison parameter works fine

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's an example for simplicity... in my code thers is a calculation perform on the entity. Updated question accordingly

Comment: If the rounding is just for the final result without affecting filters or any other data retrieval, what's the problem with rounding client-side?

Comment: @Alejandro I just don't want to have to care if the query is executed or not... I'm also having this issue with automapper, using projectTo vs Map. And calculating sum, of rounded values, in group by.

Comment: @moi_meme Try replacing the `ToList` call with `AsEnumerable` to avoid immediate execution. But the final `First` will always run it immediately, as it fetches a single normal value instead of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @Alejandro this will not change the end result.

Comment: Try [`DbFunctions.Truncate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncate(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.Truncate(System.Nullable{System.Decimal},System.Nullable{System.Int32})), maybe after adding 0.5 to make it round instead of truncate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25933869/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-double-rounddouble-int32-syste) it doesn't look like what you're asking is possible. The answer to that question also recommends fetching the data using AsEnumerable, as other comments on this question have, and doing your rounding on the in-memory data using a local query.

```
var rawData = db.Entities.Select(x => 0.5); 
var rounded =  rawData.AsEnumerable().Select(x => Math.Round(x, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```